# 'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_cloning'

Tags: django

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  90.                 response = middleware_method(request)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py" in process_request
  55.             if request.user.is_authenticated():
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in inner
  213.             self._setup()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in _setup
  298.         self._wrapped = self._setupfunc()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py" in <lambda>
  18.         request.user = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: get_user(request))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py" in get_user
  10.         request._cached_user = auth.get_user(request)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py" in get_user
  140.         user_id = request.session[SESSION_KEY]
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py" in __getitem__
  47.         return self._session[key]
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py" in _get_session
  173.                 self._session_cache = self.load()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py" in load
  20.                 expire_date__gt=timezone.now()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in get
  151.         return self.get_queryset().get(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
  300.             clone = clone.order_by()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in order_by
  724.         obj = self._clone()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cacheops/query.py" in _clone
  332.         if self._cloning:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /
Exception Value: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_cloning'

Local Variables:
self    : Error in formatting: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_cloning'
kwargs  : {}
setup   : False
klass   : None
```

The setup works fine on local dev machine, but when I try to move it to a development server, I keep getting this error.
Even if `cacheops` is removed from the Installed Applications, the problem persists.
Running on `django-cacheops==1.3.1`

Comment: I'm faced with this error some time ago - I don't know the reason, but in the ``install_cacheops`` ``_cloning`` can't be monkey patched for ``QuerySet``. In my case I disabled ``cacheops`` by this:       ``import cacheops.query as cq;
cq.installed = True``

Comment: @erthalion This doesn't quite work for me. I tried `import cacheops.query as cq; cq.installed = True` in my project's __init__.py file but I still get this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is fixed in current master.

Note that current master has gone far from 1.3.1 ([see changelog](https://github.com/Suor/django-cacheops/blob/master/CHANGELOG)). I intend to publish it as 2.0.0 soon, but you can start using it now - just install or clone it from github. [2.0.0-rc1](https://github.com/Suor/django-cacheops/tree/2.0.0-rc1) is no less stable than 1.3.1.

**EDIT:** Cacheops 2.0 is released, so you can just `pip install -U django-cacheops` now.